# R - NLP - text cleaning

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I am new to text mining and, currently, I stuck with this kind of pattern

```
pattern = c(
    "<f0><U+009F><U+0098><U+00AD>", 
    "<f0><U+009F><U+0099><U+008F>",
    "<f0><U+009F><U+008F><U+00BF> ",
    "<f0><U+009F><U+0098><U+0082>", 
    " <f0><U+009F><U+00A4><U+00B7>",
    "  <f0><U+009F><U+008F><U+00BD><U+200D><U+2640><U+FE0F>\r\nBody",
    " <f0><U+009F><U+00A4><U+00A3>", 
    " <f0><U+009F><U+0099><U+0084> ", 
    "  <f0><U+009F><U+0099><U+0084>",
    "  <f0><U+009F><U+0099><U+0083>",
      "<f0><U+009F><U+0098><U+00B4>",
     "Hello")
```

I would like to receive only pattern = "Hello" and exclude all the other text.

I tried the following but I failed immediately:

```
gsub(c, "<f0><U+00F><U+[0-9]><U+[a-zA-Z0-9]>*, replacement = "")
```

So, I tried to break it down:

```
a = gsub(c, pattern = "<f0>", replacement = "")
```

->result `<fo>` drops, so it is a good sign but when I do the next step

```
gsub(a, pattern = "<U+009F>", replacement = "")
```

->result: `<U+009F>` remains.
Do you have some ideas?
I appreciate any kind of suggestions!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to clean your text. There were no criteria given to allow removal of "Body".

```
x <- pattern # to avoid ambiguity in function parameters

# by finding words longer than two letters (so not 'a' or 'I' either)
words <- unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\b[[:alpha:]]{2,}\\b", x, perl=TRUE)))
words

#[1] "Body"  "Hello"

# by removing unwanted characters and character sequences
cleaned <- gsub("(<[^>]{0,}>|\\r|\\n)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
# and removing leading and trailing spaces
cleaned <- gsub("^ {1,}| {1,}$", "", cleaned, perl=TRUE)
cleaned[cleaned != ""]

#[1] "Body"  "Hello"
```